# Problem with @Push when tab is not in focus or not visible / Vaadin 24 / Quarkus Jakarta EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, push, quarkus, vaadin24

I have a Vaadin 24 setup and we are using the Broadcaster do push events from a rabbitmq queue to the ui.
This workes almost* like it's supposed to work if the tab that receives the push is in focus.
The message is received and ackd and the broadcaster delivers the message to the respective view within half a secon max.
if the tab is not in focus, then this process taks about 4 seconds.
is there a setting that could be made to speed up this process and treat the tab the same way as if it is visible?

Any hint would be appreciated.
If more information is needed, just leave a comment

I already tried to disable all security with the NavigationAccessControl, but then the corresponding session can't be loaded anymore.

*"almost" means, the broadcaster triggers a navigate to a new view and it instanciates the view again instead of reusing the instance that is already there.

Comment: And by "tab" you mean what? Browser-Tab? Vaadin TabSheet/Tab?

Comment: Sorry for being too unspecific. By tab i mean browser tab.

Comment: So the problem is, that if a user runs a browser-tab in the background, this "blocks" your whole broadcaster-setup on the server side? If that's the case, it sounds like you should decouple the dispatch from the propagation? In any case: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- or at least less prose and more code.

Comment: Hi cfrik,
Thank you for Responding.
The problem is that it's just slower than when the tab is visible.
The Server logs don't reveal anything other than it just does nothig.